# Windows C++ delegation with design implications

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a multithreading C++ design question for Windows. Suppose I have a   C++ class as follows:

`class CCamera_AxisNew : public CCamera_IPBase64` and suppose in the base class, CCamera_IPBase64, implementation of `PTZThreadProc(..)` , I read commands from a queue and asynchronously send PTZ commands only through either

1. the object pointer indirectly, `IPTZControl->SetProperty(..)` where the object pointer `IPTZControl = new CCamera_AxisNew`  or other similar constructors or
2. directly through `this->SetProperty()`

   The method `PTZThreadProc(..)` is spawned on a separate thread.

Also, in the class `CCamera_IPBase64`, I can bypass the `PTZThreadProc(..)` which runs on a separate thread by synchronously sending non-PTZ commands through either

1. the object pointer indirectly,  `IPTZControl->WriteCamera(...)`, or
2. directly through `this->WriteCommand(..)`.

The client program sends requests through a REST endpoint to  an `CCamera_IPBase64` object which uses a main thread to receive the request and places only PTZ commands on a queue.

My question is it better to use  delegation `IPTZControl->SetProperty(..)` or avoid delegation such as `this->SetProperty()`

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please format your question.

Comment: @n.m. Could you tell me how to format my question in  the gray area at the bottom. Thank you very much.

Comment: Click edit, select code and click the {} code formatting button, or indent every line with four extra spaces. Then remove code formatting from the last lines. Then read the help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: @Sami Kuhmonen, Thank you for your comment. I just tried indent ing every line with four extra spaces and removing code formatting from the last lines.

Comment: @n.m., Thank you for your comment. I just tried indent ing every line with four extra spaces and removing code formatting from the last lines.

Comment: @n.m., Could you please provide me with your opinion of my answer? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to avoid delegation by using this->SetProperty() and taking advantage of inheritance since it avoids extra redundant code required by the delegation design pattern.